# Different results inside and outside of a user-defined function,why?

Tags: r, function

I have a function for calculating an index called 'MCI'. The codes are

```
mci<-function(Data){
    N<-dim(Data)[1]
    L<-dim(Data)[2]
    r <- rowSums(Data)      
    i.sc <- colSums(Data)       
    r.matrix <- matrix(r,N,1) %*% matrix(1,1,L)
    p.cor.i  <- (i.sc/N)                
    p.cor.i.matrix  <- t(matrix(p.cor.i,L,N))
    gutt <- r.matrix - t(matrix(1:L,L,N))
    gutt<<- ifelse(gutt<0,0,1)
    antigutt <- (L-r.matrix) - t(matrix(1:L,L,N))
    antigutt<<- ifelse(antigutt<0,1,0)
    Covgp<-diag(cov(t(gutt),t(p.cor.i.matrix)))
    Covdp<-diag(cov(t(Data),t(p.cor.i.matrix)))
    Covagp<-diag(cov(t(antigutt),t(p.cor.i.matrix)))
    MCI <- (Covgp-Covdp)/(Covgp-Covagp)
    return(MCI)
}
```

on a data set like this:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1   1  1  1  1  0  1
2   0  0  0  1  0  0
3   1  1  0  1  1  1
4   1  1  1  1  0  1
5   1  0  1  0  0  0
6   1  1  1  1  1  1
7   1  1  1  0  1  1
8   0  1  1  1  1  1
9   1  1  0  1  1  1
10  0  1  1  0  0  0
```

it returns:

```
[1] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf
```

but if I calculate each part of the function independently the result will be:

```
[1] -Inf  NaN  NaN -Inf 0.3333333  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 0.0000000
```

Why this happens and how can I prevent this in future programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are the problem:

```
gutt<<- ifelse(gutt<0,0,1)

antigutt<<- ifelse(antigutt<0,1,0)
```

You're assigning to an object in the enclosing environment, and not modifying the object (with the same name) in the function's environment.  When you assign to `gutt` in the first of these lines, it does not affect `gutt` in the function, that you then use a few lines later.

Change these two lines to read:

```
gutt<- ifelse(gutt<0,0,1)

antigutt<- ifelse(antigutt<0,1,0)
```

and the function agrees with running the code line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks.It solved the problem.Is it a difference between global and local variables?

Comment: Yes.  You've created local variables, which will be used by default by these names (`gutt` and `antigutt`).  But the `<<-` assignment modifies a different environment, therefore a different variable.

Comment: I see.So in future use I should avoid `<<-` right?I did that based on a suggestion.

Comment: `<<-` is a function side-effect, and should generally be avoided.